# Streaming Video from a server with Intent.VIEW_ACTION

Tags: android, video

The code that I use to stream the video:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(target.getBLOBVideoUrl());
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(myUri, URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(myUri.toString()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

The function getBLOBVideoUrl() returns a URI (in String format). The Video is an MP4 file.

Whenever I try to play the video with the above code, I get the following error message in the Photos app - Couldn't play video.

However, if instead of playing the video, I download it, then there is no issue. I can download it and it works fine.

So, could anyone inform me how I can get a more detailed error message or of a better way to stream a video from a server?